# Strings Merging in C#

Tags: c#, string

please I want to merge strings of these nature by column in C#:

```
11111111111
01001111101
10111101010
```

The procedure for output: Once a column have zero(0) that column turns to zero(0). So expected result for above input should be:
00001101000

Note: My own way was to use mathematical solution via array and looping but I think I should ask if there is a simple way of achieving this in c#. My method seems to take more time if the rows are much.

Comment: Are these strings large, or only up to 64 characters?

Comment: hint: stringBin to number, then apply an AND between them

Comment: Do you need to do this as an exercise, or is the goal to actually find the result?

Comment: You can post your current solution on CodeReview. Right now it looks like you are asking to have someone do your homework.

Comment: Actually i am working on a project module and I encounter a problem of this nature. I will send my solution very soon while I await the outcomes from others.

Answer (score 1):

a way to solve this is to turn the stringBin to a number, then apply an AND between them

```
public static void Main()
{

    string x1 = "11111111111";
    string x2 = "01001111101";
    string x3 = "10111101010";
    long result1 = Convert.ToInt64(x1, 2);
    long result2 = Convert.ToInt64(x2, 2);
    long result3 = Convert.ToInt64(x3, 2);
    long res = result1 & result2 & result3;
    string binary = Convert.ToString(res, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("This is the result: " + binary);
}
```